# Maltego stuck in Starting Modules Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Maltego 4.2 + Java 11 on Ubuntu 18.04, and when I run this its always get stuck on "Starting Modules", any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Same issue but fixin the resolution and changing screens is not working for me.
It all started when Maltego updated

Answer (score 1):

Maltego only supports Java 8, unfortunately. You will need to install the java 8 runtime which can be done with the following command:
`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 1):

Clear your Desktop then start Maltego. When it freezes on "Starting Modules" watch your current workspace in your menu bar. If the square suddenly appears on it you have my problem.

It turns out Maltego has a "Master Password" screen that you need to type password in. But that window opens behind load screen for some reason, and you can't click on it or move loading screen to reveal it. You can also see this screen pop up in front of loading screen if you try to restart system or logout. But that shuts down Maltego.

My solution was to switch the order of my desktops in "Display" options until the "Master Password" screen pops on one of them and loading screen stayed on another.

If you don't have two monitors maybe changing desktop resolution would help. But I can't test that because the problem is solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same problem on maltego 4 running on Kali VM via VMware player.

Oh my, there is really a master password prompt that appears, but stays behind the splashscreen. You will get a glimpse of it only if you restart/shutdown.

I kept on altering size of the VM windows, as the kali OS kept adjusting resolution within itself, soon I was able to get the window.

U can try experimenting with resolution.
Set low res, launch maltego, when window sign appears on workspace switcher- set to higher res.
Then try adjusting window size & drag it out of the splashscreen area.

It just asks to set a master password...kinda like you set in Orace SQL stuff
[image: see right screen]

Answer (score -1):

[image][image][image]

1. open maltego.
2. once the box shows up in workspace as maltego reaches Starting Modules... Simply enter kali undercover mode.
3. You will see the master password screen flash. If you are quick enough... You can take down this flying bird.